# Converting application.cfm to application.cfc, losing session management

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, application.cfm

I've got an old site that hadn't been updated in a while, and when I went to add some new code I decided to upgrade to the application.cfc.  Clearly I'm not understanding how it should work, because once I switched it started ignoring the session variable set when the user logs in.

My application.cfm:

```html
<cfcomponent>
<cfset request.root="">
<cfapplication 
  name = "SCR"
        sessionmanagement = "Yes"
        sessiontimeout = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#"
        applicationtimeout = "#CreateTimeSpan(0,12,0,0)#">
</cfcomponent>
```

My application.cfc

```html
<cfcomponent> 
    <!--- Set up the application. --->
    <cfset THIS.Name = "SCR" />
    <cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 12, 0, 0 ) />
    <cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
    <cfset THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 3, 0, 0 ) />
    <cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = true />
    <cfset request.root="">

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
        <cfargument name="requesturi" required="true"/>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What does the session cookie say?

Comment: Just making sure, 'a' should be capitalized for `Application.cfc`.

Comment: What is the justification for capital `a` ?

Comment: A as in Adobe? j/k - Anyway, you have to name the file `Application.cfc`, especially when running Linux.

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive and they defined that the file's name needs to be ```Application.cfc```, not ```application.cfc``` when they compiled their code. No joke.